# Problem with the navigation bar

Tags: css, navigation

i have customize the navigation bar for an company, I did the edit in the masterpage and the css in sharepoint:theme, but how come the subsites won't inherit the modification that i did in the css.

Note: I only did the modification is the CSS Sharepoint Theme and not the Sharepoint csslink.

Comment: It's better to reference a custom CSS-file than to edit the default theme CSS.

Comment: Hi, can you help me out. i want to know how to create a custom css-file?

Answer (score 1):

If you have publishing features enabled for this site collection you can push the master pages, theme, and alternate CSS down to all sub sites very easily following these steps:

1. Go to `Site Settings` -> `Look and Feel` -> `Master Page`.
2. There are four different things you can modify here (Site Master Page, System Master Page, Theme, & Alternate CSS URL).
3. For each of these you can push whichever combination of them down to your sub sites by checking the `Reset all subsites to inherit this site master page setting` box and clicking `OK`.